# Why does the received state disappear in a moment?

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

I'm trying to dispatch actionC from TestClass so that Labelclass can receive the state change from reducer as below.

**TestClass**

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {text:props.text,onClick:props.onClick}
    this.onInput = this.onInput.bind(this)
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
  }
  onInput(e){
    this.setState({text:e.target.value})

  }
  onSubmit(e){
    this.state.onClick(this.state.text)
  }
  render(){
    return <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
      <input value={this.state.text} onChange={this.onInput} />
      <button type="submit">Add Todo</button>
      </form>
      </div>

  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps_Test(dispatch,ownProps){
 return {onClick:(id)=>dispatch(actionC(id))}
  }
Test.propTypes = {
  text:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onClick:PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
 Test = connect(null,mapDispatchToProps_Test)(Test)
```

**LabelClass and Entry**

```
class Label extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {text:props.text}
  }
  render(){
    return <div> Hello<label>{this.props.text}</label></div>
  }

}
function mapStateToProps_Label(state,ownProps){
  return {
      text:state.text
    }
  }
 Label = connect(mapStateToProps_Label)(Label)
Label.propTypes = {
  text:PropTypes.string.isRequired

}

const App = () =>(
 <div>
    <Test text="" onSubmit onClick />
    <Label text=""/>
  </div>

)

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

**Action and Reducer**

```
const CDD_TODO = 'CDD_TODO'
const {PropTypes} = React;
const {createStore} = Redux;
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;
let store = createStore(reducer)
//action
function actionC(text) {
  console.log(CDD_TODO)
  return { type: CDD_TODO, text:text }
}

function reducer(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CDD_TODO:
      console.log("action",action.text)
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        text:action.text
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

The trouble is **the output from LabelClass render() becomes invisible at once 
after displayed in a moment**.

I want it not to disappear. What is the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't map the value `text` from your reducer you created but you mapped the reducer it self. In your case, you have to map the `text` value from the reducer named `text`:

```
function mapStateToProps_Label(state,ownProps){
  // state.text is the state of your reducer
  // state.text.text is one of the state value
  return {
    text:state.text.text
  }
}
```

Besides, from what I see, you needn't a state in `Label`:

```
class Label extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <div> Hello<label>{this.props.text}</label></div>
  }
}
```

Same thing in `Test`: for `onClick` on `this.state` is useless:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { text: props.text }
        this.onInput = this.onInput.bind(this)
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
    }
    onInput(e) {
        this.setState({ text: e.target.value });

    }
    onSubmit(e) {
        this.props.onClick(this.state.text);
    }
    render() {
        return <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <input value={this.state.text} onChange={this.onInput} />
                <button type="submit">Add Todo</button>
            </form>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

I think you should put a breakpoint in `mapStateToProps` to see if `text` si modified after having been set. You should put a break point in the reducer to see if an action dispatch an action that erase the text data.

Comment: Thanks a lot!It worked.
state.text in mapStatetoProps was reference to reducer,as you said.
I could confirm it by changing default state argument in reducer function.

As you said, what I dispatched is meaningless because not mapped at all.
I will confirm what you said by writing a little more constructive reducer next time.

...My problem wasn't in reducer, but  I forgot e.preventDefault()...